# Does the Hellsing manga cover more material than either anime series?

Tags: hellsing

Does the Hellsing manga cover more material than either anime series? I read the wikipedia page, but didn't see any mention of it.  For example, does the manga continue the story where the animes leave off?

I'm not a big manga fan, so I don't know how books and chapters translate to anime episodes in general, let alone to this one.

Watching Drifters makes me want more, so I started rewatching Hellsing Ultimate and I'm thinking about getting or reading their mangas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to run with the assumption that you mean which goes more in depth with certain things. And even then I'd have to say neither really. I own the manga and have watched both anime and they all seem to have the same amount of focus and detail. The anime is just longer and more drawn out because it's an anime.

It was clarified that you probably meant about filler and such well the original anime is kinda faithful until episode 6 when it just leaves completely. However Hellsing Ultimate covers the manga perfectly and completely with no filler as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Usually, for question like this, OP wants to know what's considered as the source material, and whether the adaptation is following the source material faithfully (1-to-1 conversion), or have additional/filler story, or just fully diverge from the source (i.e. original story)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that was vague.  I added some clarity.